# No me funcionan ambas condiciones del if, con el AND solo una a la vez

Tags: condiciones, bucles, validación, login, local-storage

para un proyecto estoy intentando una validación desde el local storage, con un for y key que me trae los valores almacenados.
La idea es que desde el input compare a través del IF y si es correcto haga una u otra cosa. Para probar el funcionamiento correcto del IF puse directamente ambos strings, usuario y contraseña para que compare con lo contenido en el local storage. El tema es que solo me levanta el primer dato y ya lo da como valido, o de a uno a la vez, no me toma el AND para que valide usuario y contraseña contra lo que hay en el local Storage. Probe diferentes sintaxis y nada, sigue pasando lo mismo.

Dejo el codigo, la primera parte es el registro que guarda en el LS y la segunda es donde debiera poder hacer la validación...

```
document.getElementById("nuevo-usuario").addEventListener("submit", nuevoUsuario,false);
```

```
        function nuevoUsuario (){

    const usuarioIngresado = document.getElementById("usuario");
    const passwordIngresado = document.getElementById("pass");

                 const user = JSON.stringify(usuarioIngresado.value);
                 const pass = JSON.stringify(passwordIngresado.value);

                 localStorage.setItem(user, user);
                 localStorage.setItem(pass, pass);

           
}
```

//INICIO DE CESION

```
document.getElementById("usuario-registrado").addEventListener("submit",inicioCesion);
```

```
function inicioCesion(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

//RECORRO EL LOCAL STORAGE PARA OBTENER LAS KEYS
 
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
   let clave = localStorage.key(i);
   let login = JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem(clave));
   
   console.log(login);

    //EL CONDICIONAL PARA COMPARAR Y VALIDAR LAS EXPRESIONES (ESTA ES LA ULTIMA QUE PROBE, PERO INTENTE DE VARIAS MANERAS, PERO NO HAY CASO, NO ME VALIDA AMBAS EXPRESIONES

    let nombre = "Cristian"
    let contra = "1234"

    if (login == nombre && contra) { 
       
        console.log(' Alcoyana Alcoyana');
    }
     else {
        console.log(":((");
    }
     
} 
    
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Supongo que el problema es aquí: `if (login == nombre && contra) {  console.log(' Alcoyana Alcoyana'); } else { console.log(":(("); }` Pues bien: ¿qué hace el código y qué debería hacer? ¿Qué valor tienen los datos que estás evaluando?

Comment: Buenas! el codigo deberia evaluar y comparar ambos, nombre y contra(contrasenia) que asigne en la variable y previamente fueron cargados en el local storage,  login trae el key meiante la iteracion en el FOR, y asi la idea es que compruebe que tanto el usuario como la contrasenia se ecuentren alamacenadas ahi, pero el IF no contempla ambas condiciones

Comment: Prueba a poner esto antes del if: `console.log('Login: '+login+ ' nombre: '+nombre+ ' contra: '+contra + '\n');` y luego revisa la consola. Ten en cuenta que tu código se ejecuta dentro de un bucle. De todos modos, no queda claro cuál es el comportamiento que esperas realmente.

Comment: El comportamiento seria en este caso y como prueba, que si el input del usuario(en este caso para probar hice la variable) es "Cristian" y la contrasenia "1234" el console.log me arroje alcoyana alcoyana (posteriormente la idea es que se redirija al sitio) Lo que me pasaste me sirvio para ver que sucede, y es que la iteracion solo compara con la primer condicion (Cristian en este caso)

Comment: Finalmente aplique 

'''
  let nombre = "Cristian"
    let contra = "1234"

    if (login == nombre) {
        console.log(' Alcoyana Alcoyana');
    } else if (login == contra) {
        console.log(' Alcoyana Alcoyana');
    }
    else {
        console.log(":((");
    };
```
Y me resultó funcional a lo que necesitaba! gracias A.Cedano por ayudarme a pensar, estaba bloqueado

Comment: @Pax Si has encontrado la solución estaria bien que publicaras tu mismo una respuesta completa. Léete [answer] para aprender como redactar buenas respuestas, y de paso haz el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

El tipo de [operador lógico](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_l%C3%B3gicos) que necesitas es un `OR` no un `AND`, porque lo que quieres verificar es si `login` coincide con `nombre` O si coincide con `contra`.

Por tanto, en un solo condicional tendrías que poner esto: `if (login == nombre || login == contra) {`, donde `||` significa OR (que coincida uno u otro).

Veamos dos ejemplos, con valores puestos a mano, sólo para prueba:

#### Ejemplo 1

```js
let login = "Cristian";
let nombre = "Cristian";
let contra = "1234";

if (login == nombre || login == contra) {
  console.log(' Alcoyana Alcoyana');
} else {
  console.log(":((");
}
```

#### Ejemplo 2

```js
let login = "1234";
let nombre = "Cristian";
let contra = "1234";

if (login == nombre || login == contra) {
  console.log(' Alcoyana Alcoyana');
} else {
  console.log(":((");
}
```

Si quieres simplificar, también puedes combinar con un [operador ternario](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operador_condicional_ternario).

#### Ejemplo con ternario

```js
let login = "1234";
let nombre = "Cristian";
let contra = "1234";

let msg = (login == nombre || login == contra) ? 'Alcoyana Alcoyana' : ':((';

console.log(msg);
```